# Testing upload watir and rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to test upload pictures/document on web pages using watir/watir-webdriver, but everything I tried does not work.

For example, uploading pictures on Imgur:

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'rspec'

describe "Upload test" do

  before(:all) do 
      @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
      @browser.goto("https://imgur.com/")
  end

  context "Upload test" do
    it "can upload picture" do
      @browser.link(:text, "upload images").click
      @browser.file_field(:name, "img_path").set("img_path")
      @browser.button(:value,"Save").click
    end
  end

  after(:all) do
    @browser.close unless debugging?
  end

end
```

There is an error.

```
Failures:

  1) Upload test Upload test can upload picture
     Failure/Error: @browser.link(:text, "upload images").click

     Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException:
       unable to locate element, using {:text=>"upload images", :tag_name=>"a"}
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:536:in `assert_element_found'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:508:in `assert_exists'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:114:in `click'
     # ./PROBA.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 11.47 seconds (files took 0.19261 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./PROBA.rb:13 # Upload test Upload test can upload picture
```

I have tried to upload it on other sites, but I could not. Can anybody show me a correct way to upload document using watir? I think there is some trick using "flash" buttons, but I am not sure?

Comment: What happens?  If an error is thrown, please include the stacktrace.  Also, the `set` method that's chained to the `file_field` method takes a directory path (to the image) as an argument.

Comment: I have included error stacktrace now..

Comment: There's no link with text of "upload images".  There's a span, tho: `<span class="upload-btn-text">upload images</span>`  And a link with intially-capitalized text: `<a class="creation-dropdown-upload" href="javascript:;">Upload Images</a>`

Answer (score 0):

That error is saying that it doesn't see a link with the text "upload images" on the page, which has nothing to do with file uploading.
That being said, if the text field is already visible, you should be doing:
`@browser.file_field(name: 'img_path').set @file_path`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your locator is accurate.  In your example, you are targeting text that doesn't exist (i.e. there's no link with text of "upload images").

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto('http://imgur.com/')

b.span(text: "upload images").click

# alternately:
# b.div(class: "selection icon icon-arrow-down").click
# b.link(text: "Upload Images").click
```